# App.Config Read Button Enum Value

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, radio-button, app-config

I just hit this problem, that I have 2 `RadioButton` in my class, the value of each `RadioButton` should been read from class-file-Enum,

lets say :

```
Enum Status {    
Good,
Bad
}
```

I have no problem to call the value from my `Main`, But im trying to put this into App.Config Like this:

```
<add key="ClassRadioButton1Status"  value="Good"/>
<add key="ClassRadioButton2Status"  value="Bad"/>
```

and also i created one general class for my app.Config like this :

```
 public static string ClassRadioButton1Status= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClassRadioButton1Status"];
 public static string ClassRadioButton2Status= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClassRadioButton2Status"];
```

Now inside my `Main`, i want to call this `RadioButton` like this and assign the value from enum :

```
Public void processing (){
    if (RadioButton.Checked == True ){     
    // here i have to Assign the Value from Enum to This:
    Class.eStatus =// how to do from here?!!!!!!    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you specifying the values of your status in both the app.config AND as a compiled enum? Is your question really how to parse a string value to get the value of an enum? If it is then lookup Enum.Parse()

Comment: Matt : Whats your suggestion? How to do it?!

Comment: You can use Enum.GetNames() to retrieve the names of your enum values (thus making the settings keys in your app.config redundant) and Enum.Parse() to parse a string to an enum value.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved (as Matt already stated) with something like this:

```
Public void processing (){
    if (RadioButton.Checked == True ){     
    // here i have to Assign the Value from Enum to This:
    Class.eStatus =(Status) Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), ClassRadioButton1Status);
    }
}
```

**Note**

You also should check if `Enum.IsDefined` in case someone wrote some rubbish to the AppSettings